# Having trouble creating a PHP form in a web site

Tags: php, html, contact-form

I have created a web site and need to create a contact form that sends an email.  I have created a contact.php form and my index.html file refers to it in the top menu under Contact Us.  When you click on "Contact Us" it gives me an error of "This page isn’t working www.drjenniferjill.net is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500".

I have tried a simpler test form and I received the same error. I have tried other examples with similar results.

```
    <?php

if($_POST["submit"]) {
$recipient="drjennif@drjenniferjill.net";
$subject="Form to email message";
$sender=$_POST["sender"];
$senderEmail=$_POST["senderEmail"];
$message=$_POST["message"];

$mailBody="Name: $sender\nEmail: $senderEmail\n\n$message";

mail($recipient, $subject, $mailBody, "From: $sender 
 <$senderEmail>");

 $thankYou="<p>Thank you! Your message has been sent.</p>";
 }

<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Contact form to email</title>
</head>

<body>

<?=$thankYou ?>

<form method="post" action="contact.php">
    <label>Name:</label>
    <input name="sender">

    <label>Email address:</label>
    <input name="senderEmail">

    <label>Message:</label>
    <textarea rows="5" cols="20" name="message"></textarea>

    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

When you click on "Contact Us" it gives me an error of "This page isn’t working www.drjenniferjill.net is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500".  I expected a form that can be completed to send an email.

Comment: You don't appear to close off your PHP; there's no `?>` before you start your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

```php
<?php

if ($_POST["submit"]) {
    $recipient = "drjennif@drjenniferjill.net";
    $subject = "Form to email message";
    $sender = $_POST["sender"];
    $senderEmail = $_POST["senderEmail"];
    $message = $_POST["message"];

    $mailBody = "Name: $sender\nEmail: $senderEmail\n\n$message";

    mail($recipient, $subject, $mailBody, "From: $sender <$senderEmail>");

    $thankYou = "<p>Thank you! Your message has been sent.</p>";
}
?>

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Contact form to email</title>
</head>

<body>

<?=$thankYou ?>

<form method="post" action="contact.php">
    <label>Name:</label>
    <input name="sender">

    <label>Email address:</label>
    <input name="senderEmail">

    <label>Message:</label>
    <textarea rows="5" cols="20" name="message"></textarea>

    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

1. You need to close PHP tag `?>` before starting your HTML markup

Also, please add these 3 lines at the beginning of your PHP script

```php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

It will start to display PHP errors instead of just `This page isn’t working www.drjenniferjill.net is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500` and you can understand where do you have an error.

Comment: Configuring the error reporting from inside the script will of course _not_ work in a situation where a syntax error prevents the whole script from being executed in the first place.